# How to push tasks to remote Hadoop/Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hadoop

I have access to a `Hadoop` cluster provided by a third party. Currently, I use `Spark` on this cluster by logging in to a [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) notebook online. So I write my `Spark` code in a browser window in the moment, which I find not very handy.

**I wonder what options are avalable to code on my local computer and "push" tasks to the remote Spark/Hadoop cluster?**

So instead of coding in a browser window, I would be able to use (for instance) RStudio, write SparkR code, and execute the code on the remote cluster.

Since I'm rather new to this architecture, I'm thankful for any hints.

Note: This question is not about retrieving data from the `Hadoop` cluster. I already have a `OCDB` connection, so that I can can make `SQL` like queries.

Comment: Use [`spark_submit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)